# Optaplanner how to combine forEachIncludingNullVars with IfNotExist

Tags: optaplanner

I have this constraint, that is suppose to find out if no slots have been used at all for any workitem and penalize it. And it  works, as long af all WorkItems are not nulled, but the they have nullable planningentities, so sometime the will not appear in this constraint.

```
protected Constraint somePenalty(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Slot.class)
                .ifNotExists(WorkItem.class, Joiners.equal(Function.identity(), WorkItem::getSlot))     
                .groupBy((slot)->1,ConstraintCollectors.count())
                .penalizeConfigurable((a,countRes)-> countRes ) 
                .asConstraint(MeetingConstraintConfiguration.UNUSED_SLOT);
    }
```

Im trying to change it to include null slots as a new stream but the ifnotexits need a new class as an argument, but i dont need to join the Workitem again as above, rather I need to reference  the one from the stream i just joined with, but not sure how to reference it ?

```
    protected Constraint somePenalty(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Slot.class)
                .join(constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(WorkItem.class)
                                                            ^
                .ifNotExists(WorkItem.class  < ( this should ref the stream above instead)          , Joiners.equal(Function.identity(), WorkItem::getSlot))        
                
                .groupBy((slot)->1,ConstraintCollectors.count())
                .penalizeConfigurable((a,countRes)-> countRes ) 
                .asConstraint(MeetingConstraintConfiguration.UNUSED_SLOT);
    }
```

Comment: It would help to know the exact relationship between WorkItem and Slot. Anyway, there is the ifNotExistsIncludingNullVars() to get rid of the unnecessary join.

Comment: thx, well. the Workitem is the PlanningEntity and the Slot a PlanningVariable on that, picked from a factList. Slots are overcontrained and hence nullable. I was not aware of the ifNotExistsIncludingNullVars() block, that worked gr8